# Azure- Column has a data type that cannot participate in a columnstore index

Tags: python, azure, databricks

I'm trying to load data to a table in Azure database using databricks. I get the following error.

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement failed. Column 'MemberNumber' has a data type that cannot participate in a columnstore index.

I created the dataframe from a view and here's the logic for view creation

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW MemberDetails_Final AS
SELECT CAST(MemberNumber AS VARCHAR(20)) AS MemberNumber
```

I've seen that columnstore index doesn't work for varchar(max) but this column is defined as varchar(20).

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

If the underlying table has a column of a data type that is not supported for columnstore indexes, you must omit that column from the nonclustered columnstore index.

**Columns that use any of the following data types cannot be included in a columnstore index:**

- ntext, text, and image
- nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) (Applies to SQL Server 2016 (13.x) and prior versions, and nonclustered columnstore indexes)
- rowversion (and timestamp)
- sql_variant
- CLR types (hierarchyid and spatial types)
- xml
- uniqueidentifier (Applies to SQL Server 2012 (11.x))

For more details, refer [Azure SQL Database - limitations and Restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-columnstore-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#LimitRest).

Hope this helps.